# How can I perform both column deletion and renaming on one Google Big Query page?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rename, sql-delete

id like to know if i can perform two different operations on one query page.
im trying to: delete some columns and rename another column. please how do i go about this?

p.s- im new to data analytics and all its tools.
p.s p.s- i use the google big query
thank you.

for renaming a column: i used the "except syntax" which worked well
i encountered problem when i wanted to "delete columns" i tried to use the "delete from" but i didn't get it. i also tried the except syntax it didnt work well.
long story short: how do i combine the two actions on the same query page?

Comment: Hello,

The error you got from delete is probably because you did not include WHERE clause, it is necessary for delete operation in BQ.